# Iterating through Product Variants

Tags: php

I need for my e-commerce website to add products with multiple variants: in the image below there is a tshirt with multiple colors, sizes and materials.

[image]

So in php I have two arrays, the red one containing the name of the variants and the green one containing the said variants.

I need to output something like this:

```
Culoare: Rosu - Marime: L - Material: Stofa

Culoare: Rosu - Marime: L - Material: Rafie

Culoare: Rosu - Marime: XL - Material: Stofa

Culoare: Rosu - Marime XL: Material: Rafie

...

Culoare: Verde - Marime: L - Material: Stofa

Culoare: Verde - Marime: L - Material: Rafie

...
```

There are 18 combinations

I tried like for hours and i can't get my head around this. Any help is apreciated!

Comment: `foreach` inside `foreach` inside `foreach`?

Comment: foreach( $values $row) {  foreach($row as $val ) {      .........      }   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this by using iteration:

```
$your_array = array(
    'Coloare'=> array('Rosu','Verde','Galben'),
    'Marime'=> array('L','XL', 'XXL'),
    'Material'=> array('Stofa','Rafie'),
);

foreach($your_array['Coloare'] as $Coloare){
    foreach($your_array['Marime'] as $Marime){
        foreach($your_array['Material'] as $Material){
            echo 'Coloare : '.$Coloare.' - Marime : '.$Marime.' - Material : '.$Material.'<br>';
        }       
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Coloare : Rosu - Marime : L - Material : Stofa
Coloare : Rosu - Marime : L - Material : Rafie
Coloare : Rosu - Marime : XL - Material : Stofa
Coloare : Rosu - Marime : XL - Material : Rafie
Coloare : Rosu - Marime : XXL - Material : Stofa
Coloare : Rosu - Marime : XXL - Material : Rafie
Coloare : Verde - Marime : L - Material : Stofa
Coloare : Verde - Marime : L - Material : Rafie
Coloare : Verde - Marime : XL - Material : Stofa
Coloare : Verde - Marime : XL - Material : Rafie
Coloare : Verde - Marime : XXL - Material : Stofa
Coloare : Verde - Marime : XXL - Material : Rafie
Coloare : Galben - Marime : L - Material : Stofa
Coloare : Galben - Marime : L - Material : Rafie
Coloare : Galben - Marime : XL - Material : Stofa
Coloare : Galben - Marime : XL - Material : Rafie
Coloare : Galben - Marime : XXL - Material : Stofa
Coloare : Galben - Marime : XXL - Material : Rafie
```

Comment: Do you want this output?

Comment: Thank you this is what i needed!