# Recursive function to iterate through t-shirt variants

Tags: php, recursion

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454214/iterating-through-product-variants) I need to put it in a function (maybe recursive) so that I pass in the array variants and it returns a single array with all the variants.

I have an array with the different t-shirt variants like this:

Color: Black, Red, Blue

Size: L, M, XL

...

The variants may differ, more sizes, les colors, or new variants like tissue variants.

I need a function that returns an array with all the iterated variants like this:

0 Color=>Black Size=>L

1 Color=>Black Size=>M

2 Color=>Black Size XL

3 Color=>Red Size=>L

4 Color=>Red Size=>M

..

I can't get around building this final array. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: are these array inside an array or are they separate array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). To answer your first question, you'll need something like this, mix and match to suite your needs:

```
function induction($arrays, $i = 0)
{
    if( ! isset($arrays[$i]))
    {
        return [];
    }
    if($i == count($arrays) - 1)
    {
        return $arrays[$i];
    }

    $temporaryCombination = induction($arrays, $i + 1);

    $result = [];

    foreach ($arrays[$i] as $value)
    {
        foreach ($temporaryCombination as $combination)
        {
            $result[] = is_array($combination)
                ? array_merge([$value], $combination) : [
                    $value,
                    $combination,
                ];
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

var_dump(induction([$color,$size,$material]));
```

Coincidently, or not, by answering your first, I've answer this question too, the above function needs just a little tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work :

```
$inventory = array();

foreach($colors as $color){
    foreach($sizes as $size){
        $inventory[] = array(
            'Color' => $color,
            'Size' => $size,
        ),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First loop through the main array say `$array` then you will get arrays containing the color & size one by one as the loop is iterating. Then you can retrieve the Colors & Sizes of the shirt with the corresponding key/index i.e `['Color']` & `['Size']` and push them to separate new arrays `$colors` & `$size`. `array_unique()` removes duplicate elements from an array.

```
$colors=[];
$sizes=[];    
foreach($array as $arr){
    $colors[]=$arr['Color'];
    $sizes[]=$arr['Size'];
}
$colors=array_unique($colors)
$sizes=array_unique($sizes)
```